# Latex-style citations in emacs and Wanderlust

Tags: emacs, email-client, citations, footnotes

I'm reading my email in emacs using Wanderlust client. I'm subscribed on a bunch of mailing lists and quite often I'm noticing well-formatted emails which employs LaTeX-style (most simple explanation for desired behavior I guess) citations for links.

For example:

```
A side note: as written in [1], "7.5. Hints and Tips for Effective Use of
Helgrind":

     3. Avoid POSIX condition variables.

Condition variables are at the core of lbzip2. I published an article on
this topic in the form of a reddit self-post, see [2].

Thanks again!
lacos

[0] http://www.cert.fi/haavoittuvuudet/joint-advisory-archive-formats.html
[1] http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.effective-use
[2] http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9ynxv/utter_verbiage_how_to_design_condition_variables/
```

Could please someone point me to the most convenient way of creating of such citations using emacs? I hope that they aren't created manually and there is a tool which I'm not aware of. :)

Thanks!

Update: I realized that I was actually looking for [footnotes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Footnotes.html), not 'citations'. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a tool all right.  At least one.  This one is called org-mode and you can spend your life in org-mode.  Suffice it to say that the learning curve for org-mode is fairly large but you might put your question to the org-mode mailing list or peruse the manuals and find a quick answer.  Google has a ton of information on org-mode.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually I just started to play with org-mode and first results looks very exciting.

Thanks for suggestion, I'm going to stick with org-mode drafting my emails.

Answer (score 4):

You can use footnote mode for that. See

http://emacsworld.blogspot.com/2008/12/footnote-mode.html